# should borders affect the layout?

Tags: css

Using a basic layout such as...

```
<div class="span-23 last" id="main">
    <div class="span-18" id="column1">
        <div class="clear span-10" id="body1"> </div>
        <div class="span-6 prepend-1 append-1" id="body2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span-5 last" id="column2"> </div>
</div>
```

When I define a border on any of the div's they either do not show up or move the page elements around.  So do borders actually take up a px count outside of a div?  If so how can I get around this?

I have seen some mention using `position:relative;` but that is not the problem here as I use that extensively normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, borders take up physical space. So, if you set a div to be 100%, then give it a 1px border, it will be 2px wider than the container it is in.

To get around it, you can decide not to set a width at all (or 'auto') so that it will automatically adjust to account for padding and borders.

Alternatively, you can nest elements, giving an outer div a specific width, then an inner div the border.

There's other options too.

ADDENDUM:

Ah, it looks like you are using blueprint.css

Blueprint.css is *not* designed to handle adding borders to the layout containers. This will break the grid.

I've modified blueprint.css in the past to accomodate this. Typically I'll add some unique classes that can be applied to span-x divs:

```
.span-border {border: 1px solid black;}
.span-8.span-border {margin-left: -1px; margin-right: 9px;}
```

The above is based on a 10px 'gutter' between columns. What you do is reduce the gutter on each side of a span-x that has a border applied to it to accommodate the space the border takes up.

Comment: Thanks for all the info.  Although outline could be a workaround, as another mentioned, I am going to use your approach and define a border element as you did.  When strict layout is important this really seems to fit the bill.  I feel dumb for overlooking it.  Maybe it is because I didn't understand the px count of a border.

Answer (score 10):

*Should* borders affect layout?  No.  Peter Paul Koch [said it best at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html), ([quoting himself](http://netdiver.net/interviews/peterpaulkoch.php)):

> Logically, a box is measured from border to border. Take a physical box, any box. Put something in it that is distinctly smaller than the box. Ask anyone to measure the width of the box. He'll measure the distance between the sides of the box (the 'borders'). No one will think of measuring the content of the box.
>
> Web designers who create boxes for holding content care about the *visible* width of the box, about the distance from border to border. The borders, and not the content, are the visual cues for the user of the site. Nobody is interested in the width of the content.

But *do* borders affect layout?  Sadly, the answer is yes.  Consider this div:

```
.foo {
    width: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

This div will actually be 512px wide, because `width` sets the width of the contents, not the div.  You have to add padding and border to get the actual width.

**Edit:** To correct this madness use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing):

```
.foo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;  /* FireFox requires the -moz- prefix */
    width: 500px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

This div will be 500px wide, even with the padding and the border.

[Demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45pT6/2/)

<sup>It doesn't work in IE7 (which has less than 1% market share).</sup>

Comment: Thanks, same info as DA but you added a funny quote...+1

Answer (score 2):

Border is counted into the whole width and height of the element.
To avoid it, use `outline`.

```
.element{
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Outline is a great alternative but note that older browsers *cough* IE *cough* will not support it.

Comment: Unfortunately outline is not that well supported across browsers and it will usually render differently in every browser engine available.

Comment: But you could still use *hacks* in IE to make it support it... And as [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp) says, "The outline property is supported in all major browsers."

Comment: It says "is supported" not "is working as expected" :) Those are two completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't specify width to any of your block level elements. Then the borders will get accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS box model defines `border` and `padding` to be outside of `width` and `height`, that is, `width` and `height` specify content area size only, and don't include `border` or `padding`.

The old IE box model, by the way, which is what you get in IE < 6, and quirks mode, included `border` and `padding` in the `width` and `height`. `outline` is somewhat like `border` but does not increase element size.

Answer (score 0):

Borders take up pixels outside of the actual element...so, if you have a `div` of `width: 20px` and `border: 1px`, the full width is `22px`. One way to get around it is to have a container with your specified width, then have an inner div with no specified width and the border.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pWB9U/